# What type of mycelium do I want to integrate into my soil to take up mercury from the lake front aquaponic garden?

Tags: fungus, aquaponic, toxicity

There's a mercury in the water near me. What type of mycelium can I use to treat the problem to get it out of the water?

I plan to use the grass that grows in a bioreactor, then put the liquid byproduct in the trash that I send to the landfill as a liquid soaked up by my trash.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because sequestration of mercury is not a gardening topic

Comment: it is if your water garden is right on the edge of a lake

Comment: Perhaps a question such as "If I irrigate my garden with water from the lake, will the mercury be taken up by my veggies?" "Some plants can absorb pollutants, are there fungi that will do the same?" would establish the garden link more directly?

Comment: https://www.epa.gov/sites/production/files/2015-08/documents/treat_tech_mercury_542r07003.pdf

Comment: they don't cover mycelium treatment for some reason

Comment: It's rather for a government agency to write a report about something which doesn't exist. On the other hand they do write about eight different *proven* methods which *do* exist.

Comment: See section 11.2 of the EPA report - which sort of explains why phytoremediation is not as easy as you would like it to be. See also https://frtr.gov/matrix2/section4/4-3.html (referenced from the EPA report).

Comment: @kevinsky that's actually phytoremediation, not mycoremediation. I do mycological stuff as it spreads quicker, not pyhtological stuff

Comment: Google 'mycoremediation for mercury' - there's some research available. Mercury is classed as a heavy metal  so you may find it under mycoremediation for heavy metals as well.